# Chart.js on Wix, Velo - refreshes, not working when clicking on publish

Tags: chart.js, velo

I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/chart.js-custom-element) to draw charts using chart.js in Wix Valo

I only placed a new button that changes the chart data like :

```
if (!chart1 ) {chart1 = new ChartJSAPI($w('#CustomElement1'));}
    chart1.customization = data_chart.customization
    chart1.data = data_chart.data 
    }
```

When I clicked on the [preview button](https://ibb.co/h79Fz1z) the chart refreshed well, but if I published it I got this error (I'm a premium customer)

```
hart.js:5552 Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.
```

How to solve this?

The all code

```
import { ChartJSAPI } from 'public/chart-api';
import { chartCustomization } from 'public/chart-customization';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(async function () {
     chart(processDataForChart(results2))

    })







 
var results2 = [
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-01-01"
        },
        trips_count: 19595
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-02-01"
        },
        trips_count: 19460
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-03-01"
        },
        trips_count: 10909
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-04-01"
        },
        trips_count: 35
    }
];


var results3 = [
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-01-01"
        },
        trips_count: 1955
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-02-01"
        },
        trips_count: 1960
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-03-01"
        },
        trips_count: 1009
    },
    {
        trip_date: {
            value: "2021-04-01"
        },
        trips_count: 3570
    }
];






// This function is determine which column will be X 

function getColumnName(jsonData) {
var columns_counter = 0
var columns = Object.keys(jsonData[0])


for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        // var value = jsonData[0][column];
    // console.log('', typeof (jsonData[0][columns[i]])

        if (jsonData[0][columns[i]].value != undefined) {
            console.log('getColumnName',columns[i])
            return columns[i];
        }

       
        
    columns_counter ++

    }

 console.log('getColumnName',columns[0])
columns[0]



}





function processDataForChart(jsonData) {

var columns = Object.keys(jsonData[0])
var dataArray = [];
var counter = 0
var labels = [];
var columns_counter = 0
var backgroundColor1 =  ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)","rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)","rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)","rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)","rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"]
var borderColor1 = ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)","rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)","rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)","rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)","rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"]
var backgroundC = []
var borderC = []
var x_axis =  getColumnName(jsonData)


columns.forEach(function(column) {


 console.log('column',column )
 
 console.log('x_axis', x_axis )
if(column != x_axis  ){

var label = [];
var type=[];
var data = [];
var backgroundC = [];
var borderC = [];
var borderWidth = [];

// console.log('columns',columns)





backgroundC.push(backgroundColor1[columns_counter]);
borderC.push(borderColor1[columns_counter]);
type.push("bar")
borderWidth.push(1)

// columns_counter ++

jsonData.forEach(function(item) {

     if (counter < 5){


    //  console.log('item[column]',item[column])
     
    // if(item[column].value == undefined){

    data.push(item[column]);
    
    // ;


    // } else{
    
    



    // }
    
    


     }
        });
 
  dataArray.push({
            label: column,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: backgroundC,
            borderColor: borderC,
            borderWidth: borderWidth
        });
 
        counter++; // Increment counter after processing a column

}

else{

jsonData.forEach(function(item) {
labels.push(item[column].value);

})

}


columns_counter ++


})


// var output = '"labels":'+ labels + ',"datasets":' +  dataArray
//  console.log('dataArray',dataArray)
// return  output


var data_charts = {
    
    data: {
        "labels": labels,
        "datasets": dataArray
    },
    
        customization: {
               
                "borderWidth": 1,
                
            
        }
    
};


return data_charts




}


var chart1

async function chart(data_chart){

//  if(chart1 == undefined){

if (!chart1 ) {chart1 = new ChartJSAPI($w('#CustomElement1'));}
chart1.customization = data_chart.customization
chart1.data = data_chart.data 
}



export function button6_click(event) {

 chart(processDataForChart(results3))


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal set of changes to the velo chart.js [tutorial](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/chart.js-custom-element)
referenced in the question, that would allow for the update of the chart. The tutorial consists in four files:

- a `Chart.JS`, which is the frontend, i.e., the javascript of the web page;
- a `chart-api.js` and a `chart-customization.js` which are part of the backend, and might be placed in the wix app's `/public/` directory
- a `chart.js`, which is the class defining the custom element displaying the chart; it might be placed in `/public/custom-elements`

The changes are to be made to the two `chart.js/Chart.JS` files; there are no changes required
for `chart-api.js` or `chart-customization.js`

To illustrate the dynamic data version we'll suppose a button (`button1`) was added to the page,
that has an click handler called `button1_click`. Also, there's a
collection `"ChartItems2"`, that has the same labels as `"ChartItems"`,
but different values for the data. On pressing `button1`, we want
the chart to update displaying the data from `"ChartItems2"`, that means
the bars of the chart will have different lengths.

### The frontend

The standard method to update the frontend is assign new data to the chart object (instance
of `ChartJSAPI`) and call its `.render()` method. This means that we have to keep
track of this object, through a global variable; Here's the updated
`Chart.JS` file:

```js
import { ChartJSAPI } from 'public/chart-api';
import { chartCustomization } from 'public/chart-customization';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

let chart = null; // ChartJSAPI instance, not chart.js instance

$w.onReady(async function () {
    chart = new ChartJSAPI($w('#customElement1'));
    chart.customization = chartCustomization;

    const chartItems = await wixData
        .query("ChartItems")
        .find()
        .then(res => res.items);

    const labels = chartItems.map(item => item.label);
    const data = chartItems.map(item => Number(item.data));
    const backgroundColor = chartItems.map(item => item.backgroundColor);
    const borderColor = chartItems.map(item => item.borderColor);

    chart.data = {
        labels,
        datasets: [{ data, backgroundColor, borderColor }]
    };
});

export async function button1_click(event) {
    if(chart){
        const chartItems2 = await wixData
            .query("ChartItems2")
            .find()
            .then(res => res.items);
            
        const dataNew = chartItems2.map(item => Number(item.data));
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataNew;
        chart.render();
    } 
}
```

### The custom element class

The changes above are the only required modifications in "Preview" mode; however,
for the "published" site, one gets the error `Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.`,
as reported in the question.

To address this issue one has to make some adjustments to the `chart.js` custom element class.
Here, one has to keep track of the chart.js instance, the result of `new Chart(...)`;
we assign this object to the property `_chart` of the `ChartElem` class; we initialize it
with `null` in the constructor:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

class ChartElem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this._root = document.createElement('canvas');
        this._root.setAttribute("id", "myChart");
        this._root.setAttribute("style", "width: 100%");
        this._shadow.appendChild(this._root);

        this._parent = document.querySelector("chart-elem");
        this._chart = null; // added
    }
    ........
```

Then, in the `render` method, we verify first if `this._chart` is initialized and
if it is, we destroy the current chart first:

```js
    ........
    render() {
        if(this._chart){ // if chart exists 
            this._chart.destroy?.();
        }
        
        const ctx = this._shadow.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        this._chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: this.chartData,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 0,
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    y: { // modified to make compatible with newer versions of chart.js
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Also note the change in the `scales` options, required to make the code compatible with newer versions of chart.js.
There are no changes to the other method of the class `ChartElem`.

Alternatively, we can use chart.js method [`update`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) method;
it has the advantage that it doesn't recreate the chart:

```js
    ........

    render() {
        if(this._chart){  // if chart exists
            this._chart.data =  this.chartData;
            this._chart.update();
            return;
        }
        
        const ctx = this._shadow.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        this._chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        ...... the same as above        
    }
```

If we know that only the values of the first (and only) dataset are changed, we can replace

```js
this._chart.data =  this.chartData;
```

with

```js
this._chart.data.datasets[0].data =  this.chartData.datasets[0].data;
```

which results in a smooth transition from the first chart view to the second, the
bars being animated from their first position to the second. That happens if the
y-axis doesn't have to be rescaled, which means that either the maximum y value is
the same, or, the option `options.scales.y.max` is set to a value that is greater
than both the maximum values (the one before and the one after the update).

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the chart.js to your code and now the chart not shown

Comment: Yeah, I see it. The code should be the way it was and it worked before. I just copied the code from the tutorial. So start with your previous code that worked and just make the three modifications I indicate

Comment: No I edit my code and added in render  `if(this._chart){
            this._chart.destroy(); // here's the required destroy
        }` and `this._chart = null` in the constructor and got the same error

Comment: I don't see how those changes can result in an error about imports. Try to  gradually revert to the original version and see if the error persists  -- for instance do you get that error when you only add `this._chart = null` in the constructor and leave anything in the original form? If there's no error try to eliminate just the `if` statement, etc.

Comment: Your answer working well